# Find Lombok getter/setter via Java Reflection API

Tags: java, reflection, lombok

Is it possible to find/invoke a getter or setter generated by the Lombok library? Standard class.getMethod doesn't work.

Comment: lombok generates these methods before the compilation phase. These methods can be found like any other method.

Comment: If it is not working I would check that lombok is setup correctly. Make sure you can compile code that uses the method before checking if reflection works.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; there is no way to differentiate writing out the stuff lombok makes for you by hand, vs letting lombok generate it, once we're down to class files (except via, I guess, line numbers in the debug table). standard `class.getMethod` will work just fine. If you're having a problem with it, perhaps edit the question (or ask a new one). You can also use `javap` (the java decompiler, ships with your JDK installation) to confirm that these methods are just there, indistinguishable from handwritten ones.